# Grub не может найти Fedora после распределения пространства диска windows 10 и последующим обновлением

Tags: linux, windows-10, grub, fedora

У меня dual-boot система: Windows 10 and Fedora 30. Проблема произошла когда я захотел расширить место под федору, и я зашел на виндовс что бы уменьшить логические диски и потом добавить его в линукс. Делал я это утилитой AOMEI(виндовс тогда распознавал логический том линукса как свободное место). Утилита перезапустила комп, уменьшила диски я хотел запустить федору и добавить места. Но винда решила сделать обнову и после перезапуска я вижу только windows boot manager без Федоры в Grub. У меня есть флешка с федорой, но там утилита disks тоже распознает место где была федора как нераспределенное. Пожалуйста помогите, потому что у меня на федоре много работы. Буду очень признателен.

Comment: … так Данііл Денисюк осознал необходимость выполнять резервное копирование.

Comment: так я не пойму это реально она удалилась или нет

Comment: ну, раз вас не насторожило «виндовс тогда распознавал логический том линукса как свободное место», то теперь придётся, прежде чем хоть что-то делать, сначала почитать много интересной информации. можете начать, например, [отсюда](https://www.altlinux.org/Rescue) (ссылку привожу потому, что там просто по-русски написано: для многих чтение по-английски даже элементарной документации — это большая проблема). удачи!

Comment: для меня чтение на английском не составлсяет труда

Answer (score 0):

Изменять размеры диска с линуксовой файловой системой следует либо с live-образа linux утилитой [GParted](https://gparted.org/), либо с загрузочного диска [Acronis Disk Director](https://www.acronis.com/en-eu/personal/disk-manager/). Проверял сам - оба способа рабочие, второй быстрее..

Устанавливать венду, также изменять разделы из-под нее, следует ПЕРЕД установкой linux, т.к. windows все линуксовые разделы считает неотформатированной областью и форматирует их по дефолу. Linux такой штуки в вендовыми разделами НЕ делает.

Это на будущее. Ну а сейчас делаем бэкапы того, что осталось, и переустанавливаем обе оси. Сначала разбиваем разделы акронисом, потом устанавливаем венду, потом устанавливаем linux.

Рекомендуемый порядок разделов:

```
1. swap                - 2 размера ОЗУ
2. root    - ext4(xfs) - ~ 20 GB
3. windows - ntfs      - ~ 20 GB
4. home    - ext4(xfs) - все, что осталось на харде
```

Comment: У меня 32 гига озу, стоит ли мне делать 64 гига swap ?

Comment: дело в том, что я место с илнуксом не трогал, я уменьшил логические диски виндовса